# Add a new field in the attribute table from derived feature

Tags: qgis-2

Is it possible to create a new field in the attribute table with the same value of the a specific derived feature? 
For example: I would like to add "feature id" -from derived feature- to "ID_der" -attribute table-

[image]

Comment: In the **Field Calculator**, try updating your "ID_der" field with the expression `$id`.